# App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP XCode 7.1

Tags: ios, ios9, app-transport-security

I have seen the App transport secuirty blocker in my code for XCode 7.1. I have tried couple of options from stackoverflow to set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true but still this is not working, Any more suggestions would really help.

Logs

```
2016-01-12 14:06:21.575 FoxNewsServic[54081:13484633] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
my info.plist looks like below. 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>KWatch WatchKit Extension</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.kone.com.watchkitextension</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>WKAppBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.kone.com.watchkitapp</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.watchkit</string>
    </dict>
    <key>RemoteInterfacePrincipalClass</key>
    <string>InterfaceController</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` instead of `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>myDomain.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>anotherDomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: @fgragilecat, what should i add for myDomain.net and anotherDomain.com, Please can you suggest, I dint understand them.

Comment: Each one is an example - you need one per domain your app hits. IE what url's is your app calling? Then add an entry in your info.plist for each domain.

Comment: The "Temporary" part must ring a warning bell (a huge one): this is a temporary key that's been used before and must not be used at the production apps now. An actual alternative is easy to find: NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads.

Comment: this is the url http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/sports , i am using a get method.

Comment: Then you need to add foxnews.com  instead of myDomain.net.

Comment: @A-Live if this a temporary workaround as i understand, what do you suggest as permanent solution ? any reference links for using https and adding the certificate to which folder / dir in your xcode project. I would rather use that as the solutions instead of workaround.

Comment: There's a table dedicated for ATS exceptions keys at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html @fragilecat you still have the "temporary" key at the very beginning.

Comment: @fragilecat I have tried adding foxnews.com in domain but i can still see the App Transport Security message in the xcode logs ? any idea what could be missing